# How does Pop3 for multiple locations work? (Fetchmail)

Tags: email, pop3, duplicate, fetchmail

I use POP3 and Fetchmail to download my gmail at home and on my work machine. But I've noticed that, although I'm using --keep to prevent it being deleted on the server, usually the messages I download at work will not show up at home. This leads me to a question I've been searching out for a while: how does POP3 "mark" a message so that, while left on the server, it isn't downloaded multiple times on one computer, and how can I download all my new gmails (or whatever other email pop3) for the day at home after having downloaded them at work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify in gmail settings that you do not want your emails to be deleted. If this option hasn't been set, gmail sees that a message has been pop'ed and will remove it. Gmail's pop implementation is a little bit different from the standard pop email servers.

UPDATE: According to Gmail's instructions(https://support.google.com/mail/answer/47948?hl=en), if you want to download your email with POP3 on multiple clients, you have to change some more settings:

> Setting up 'recent mode'
>
> In your POP client settings, replace 'username@gmail.com' in the
>   'Username' or 'Email' field with 'recent:username@gmail.com'
>
> Once you enable recent mode, please be sure to configure your POP
>   client to leave messages on the server according to the instructions
>   below:
>
> Outlook or Outlook Express: on the Advanced tab, check the box next to
>   'Leave a copy of messages on the server.' Apple Mail: on the Advanced
>   tab, remove the check next to 'Remove copy from server after
>   retrieving a message.' Thunderbird: on the Server Settings tab, check
>   the box next to 'Leave messages on server.'

Comment: Thanks for the applicable gmail-specific answer. However, I already had set "when messages are accessed with POP _keep gmail's copy in the inbox_" and it doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edit! One more request: do you know anything about my other question, about how servers actually mark kept mail as downloaded by some machine? A link would be nice, if you can find one.

Comment: POP3 RFC 1939: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt
These days, there are so many different implementations (yahoo, gmail, exchange, ...). You'd have to talk to the developers of the servers to find out. Most of them are closed source so good luck! :)